# How to resolve these warnings?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress Theme Slider and in this I used piecemaker. Can anyone help me out?

> Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in
>   the server configuration in
>   ..wp-content\themes\TheProfessional\page-full.php on line 8
>
> Warning:
>   include(http://localhost/caterer/wp-content/plugins/theme-slider/wp-theme-slider.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could
>   be found in ..wp-content\themes\TheProfessional\page-full.php on line
>   8
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'http://../wp-content/plugins/theme-slider/wp-theme-slider.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.;Drive:\xampp\php\pear\') in
>   ..\wp-content\themes\TheProfessional\page-full.php on line 8

Comment: Did you read those warnings? they provide a file and a line to look at, besides a description of the error

Comment: yes i read it, now it showing parse error after i gave the path

Comment: Parse error: parse error in \wp-content\themes\TheProfessional\page-sitemap.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

Your directive allow_url_include is turned off, if you have control over your hosting you will need to turn this on in the php.ini config and restart apache, if you don't have direct access to your hosting, you can use this code at the top of your index.php file in the root folder of wordpress to turn it on.

```
ini_set(‘allow_url_fopen’,'ON’);
```

if nothing works as outlined - here is a more detailed blog post:
[additional information](http://goffgrafix.com/blog/index.php/2010/04/if-your-server-sets-the-allow_url_fopen-and-allow_url_include-php-directives-off/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because including a file using a url (http://) is the reason behind this errors. You have to include a file using the directory path of the file not the url path. Since the files are from a certain plugin and theme then change your code to this

```
include(bloginfo('template_directory').'/page-full.php');
include (WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/theme-slider/wp-theme-slider.php');
```